# Problemas con inserción de datos en listas enlazadas en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema con la implementación de la función pushBack(), que inserta un nodo al final de la lista. Acá está el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct
{
    // Puntero al primer nodo
    Node *head;
    // Cantidad de datos
    unsigned short size;
    // Puntero al ultimo dato accedido.
    Node *current;
}List;

List *createList();
Node *createNode(int *);
void pushBack(List *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    List *lista = createList();
    pushBack(&lista, 4);
    return 0;
}


List *createList()
{
    List *list = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
    list -> head = NULL;
    list -> size = 0;
    list -> current = NULL;
    return list;
}

Node *createNode(int *data)
{
    Node *node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node -> data = data;
    node -> next = NULL;
    return node;
}
// Función para insertar un nuevo nodo al final de la lista
void pushBack(List *list, int *data)
{
    Node *node = createNode(data);
    while ( list -> head )
        list -> head = list -> head -> next;
    list -> head = node;
    list -> size ++;
}
```

Al momento de testear la funcionalidad de la función pushBack(), me aparece en la terminal : "Stack smashing detected". Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con este problema se lo agradecería mucho. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estas recorriendo adecuadamente la lista:

```
void pushBack( List *list, int *data ) {
  Node *node = createNode( data );

  ++( list->size );

  // Comprobamos si la lista está vacía.
  if( !list->head ) {
    list->head = node;

    return;
  }

  Node *current = list->head;

  while( current->next ) current = current->next;

  current->next = node;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Trauma, te agradezco mucho. Había entendido erróneamente el uso del campo current.

Comment: Nada, un placer :-)